# Android App Hangs When Running While Not USB Connected

Tags: android, multithreading, usb, freeze

My Android application runs perfectly normal when connected to the computer. However, when run while USB is disconnected, the application will hang indefinitely.
This sounds like a dumb question, but I was wondering if being plugged in gives any kind of advantages that I may be missing. Would threading act differently while connected to a computer?

Comment: `Would threading act differently while connected to a computer?` .. no I don't think so. I think there is something else going on here - you need to determine where its hanging (and if any errors are getting thrown). Does your app use USB functionality? ... I can only guess that it does depend on this functionality somehow (and that is why the problem presents itself when you unplug it).

Comment: The app contains zero USB functionality. Only used to install the application. No errors are thrown since the application just hangs. Seems to me like a threading problem but why would the USB connection affect it? It's very strange indeed. I appreciate the comment.

Comment: Very strange indeed, sorry I don't have a solution for you (I don't how/why USB would affect threading - if that is the problem it kind of suggests a race condition somewhere). I can only suggest gathering more info - trace statements, debug w/ breakpoints in emulator, etc.

Comment: Could be a power thing. Could you please connect your phone to the charger and run the application.

Comment: Thanks again Trooper. I will leave this open for any new replies but I appreciate you taking some time to respond. I will throw in log statements, but I cannot debug w/ breakpoints since it only doesn't work when the USB is disconnected.

Comment: @JayeshElamgodil Thanks for responding. Nothing changed unfortunately, but do you think that power could affect performance of the phone?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And it was caused by application managing in battery optimization (settings->battery->app launch). My application was automatically managed by system, and launch of some features was prevented in the name of saving battery. After switching to "Manage manually", and giving all permissions app is working fine.